# Is there a way to back-transform log(x+1)?

Tags: r, math

Is there a way to back-transform the mean of a vector of `log(x+1)` values in R? I tried to use the `expm1()` function from the `base` package, but the number is definitely not correct.

```
df <- c(11, 24, 21, 63, 44, 95, 12, 43, 0, 5, 26, 22, 25, 48, 86, 2)

mean(df)
```

This gives us 32.9375

Now, if we do ...

```
df.log1p <- log1p(df)
mean(df.log1p)
```

This gives us 3.0382116

Now, can I back-transform that single mean value to get the non-`log1p` mean value of 32.9375?
I used `expm1(3.0382116)` to try that but I got 19.86789.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: By properties of logarithms, the arithmetic mean of `log(x+1)` over a set of values is equal to the `log` of the geometric mean of `(x+1)` over the same set. There is no one-to-one mapping between the two means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's **not possible**. Unfortunately, `mean(log1p(x)) == mean(log(1 + x))` is *one way* operation.
Imagine

```
 A <- c(1 / exp(1) - 1, exp(1) - 1)
 B <- c(0, 0)
```

As you can see

```
 mean(A) = 0.5430806
 mean(B) = 0
```

But

```
 mean(log1p(A)) = 0
 mean(log1p(B)) = 0
```

so having `mean(log1p(...))` you *can't* get `mean(...)`. For a given `mean(log1p())` there are *infinitely many* different corresponding `mean`s whenever the collection has more than one item.

Comment: This was very easy to understand. Thank you for clarifying :)

Answer (score 2):

This is more a math question. The exponentiated value of mean(log(x)) is not equal to the mean of (x).

```
mydf <- c(5,10)
mean(mydf)
[1] 7.5
log(mydf)
[1] 1.609438 2.302585
mean(log(mydf))
[1] 1.956012
exp(mean(log(mydf)))
[1] 7.071068
```

Comment: This was also very helpful! Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 2):

@DmitryBychenko's answer clearly explains why this is not possible if you only have the mean. However, you can get an **approximate** answer if you have the mean *and the variance* by using a form of the *delta method* (this uses a second-order Taylor series approximation) which says that in general (approximately) `mean(F(x)) ~ F(mean(x)) + F''(mean(x))*var(x)/2`. For this particular problem,

```
F(x) = exp(x)-1
F''(x) = exp(x)
```

This is elementary calculus, but you can use `D(D(expression(exp(x)-1),"x"),"x")` to double-check if you want. Now:

```r
## mean and variance on the transformed scale
m <- mean(log(1+df))
v <- var(log(1+df))
## delta-method
expm1(m) + exp(m)*v/2
## [1] 35.68235
```

This is different from `mean(df)` = 32.9375, but it's much closer than the naive approach of just back-transforming the mean (`expm1(m)`=19.86789).

---

From Hilborn and Mangel *The Ecological Detective* (Princeton University Press), via Google books:

[image: derivation of Jensen's inequality approx]